# Ubuntu Update Manager won't update when "Install Updates" is clicked

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I press the "Install Updates", Update Manager goes on to refreshing the updates list but does not install them.

I can install the updates through `apt-get` though.  What could be the problem?

Comment: Are we talking about Ubuntu, or Debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about Ubuntu, and not Debian.  The following answer assumes this is the case, although you might want to clarify your question a bit more.

First, it's a bug.  Second, close the update manager, then in the upper-right corner, click on the icon representing the update manager, and select install updates.  The update manager will appear; click on the install checkbox, and they should install.

---

If the update manager is not running in the upper right-portion of the screen, yet you have updates, it could be you have some file corruption issues that can easily be fixed.  While logged into a Gnome session (regular graphical session), press Alt-F2, and type this:

```
gnome-terminal
```

Then in the terminal, type:

```
sudo apt-get clean ; sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Close the terminal once it is completely finished.  It may take a short while to force the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I cut & pasted this command into the terminal and it ran and it updated several packages, but I don't have an Update Manager icon in my top panel, at the right or anywhere else on the panel (except in System > Admin > Update Manager, of course).

Should I in fact have the UM icon in the top panel at right?  I'm running karmic on 64-bit ubuntu system75 Wild Dog desktop.

Comment: @watchpocket: this is not the place to ask a question but to answer one.